# Getting error installing RVM in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-16.04

Following the installation of RVM, I'm getting error listed below.

```
   Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgmp-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev',
    showing last 15 lines of /home/aldrien/.rvm/log/1486780247_ruby-2.3.3/package_install_gawk_libreadline6-dev_zlib1g-dev_libssl-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3_autoconf_libgmp-dev_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_libffi-dev.log
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.0+20151024-2ubuntu2) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libncurses5 (= 6.0+20151024-2ubuntu2) but 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 6.0+20151024-2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
     libreadline6-dev : Depends: libtinfo-dev but it is not going to be installed
     libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.10.2-1) but 3.11.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
     libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2f-2ubuntu1) but 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.10.2-1) but 3.11.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
    ++ /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_try_sudo()  381 > return 100
    ++ /scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu : requirements_debian_libs_install()  36 > return 100
```

Please help!